# "expected type-specifier" error in g++

Tags: c++, g++

I have a DD class

```
template<typename T>
class DD
: public IEnumerable<T>
{
    typedef IEnumerable<T> Super;
    typedef std::set<T*> Container;
```

And a method

```
template<typename T>
bool DD<T>::Enumerator::Move()
{
    if(!mIt.get()) 
       mIt.reset(
          new Container::iterator( <-----
            mContainer.GetContainer().begin()
          )
       );
       ... 
}
```

When I compile the class, I got `error: expected type-specifier`. 
What's wrong with the `Container::iterator()`?

Comment: In your other question the error was caused by an excessive `typename` keyword. In this case it is the opposite: a required `typename` is missing. Apparently, you simply accidentally misplaced it: took it from here and dropped over there :)

Comment: BTW, `Container::iterator` is not a "method". `Container::iterator` is a nested *type*. Which is why you need that `typename` there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
new typename Container::iterator
```

When you are in a C++ template, the compiler doesn't know whether Container::iterator is a type or something else. So you need to explicitly say that its a type.

On another note, creating an iterator with new is almost certainly wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
new typename Container::iterator( 
//  ^^^^^^^^
```

Without the `typename`, C++ will assume `X::Y` is a member (value/function) when X is in a template. You need the `typename` to force the compiler to interpret `X::Y` as a type.

Answer (score 2):

Make that

```
new typename Container::iterator(
```

For a thorough explanation, see [this FAQ](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#typename).