# How to use boost regex create with CString

Tags: regex, boost-regex

I try to do:

```
boost::tregex prot_mask(_T("[0-9][0-9]?"));
```

But it failed:

> Error:expected a type specifier.

It's something to do with `_T`.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: Does this answer solve your problem?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5250562/2145800

Comment: @любовь, please check my edits and make sure I didn't change the meaning of your question.  Also, questions related to regexes should always be tagged [tag:regex] in addition to the more specific tags like [boost-regex].  That will get you more, higher quality answers.